# Conditional formatting in QuickSight for rows in pivot table visualization

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to add conditional formatting for a visualization in QuickSight. My requirement is to add conditional formatting for rows. Each row represents a metric value and each column represents a week. The pivot table option lets me make the visualization to see weekly trend of metrics. The issue is that there is no way to add conditional formatting for rows of pivots tables. If I create a regular table then I lose the two dimensionality of the table i.e. can't do metric vs weekly trend.

Is there a way to create conditional formatting for rows of a pivot table or is there a way to create a two dimensional table?